# Gaussian Job File with Variables and Link1

Tags: quantum-chemistry, gaussian, high-performance-computing

I work now with larger job files and use the `--Link1--` keyword to organize up to 10 jobs in one job file. This works very well for me. But I got a lot of job series with numbered consecutively in the Titel section and the name of the specified chk-files.

This is a small sample of my code:

```
%chk=x0_ground_low.chk
%mem=80GB
%nprocshared=8
#p opt b3lyp/6-311+g(2d,p) nosymm

low optimization no.x0 ground

0 1
C         -0.65829        1.17916        0.00108
C         -1.36344       -0.02375        0.00285
C          0.73771        1.19337       -0.00082
C         -0.65909       -1.22650        0.00278
C          1.43195       -0.01475       -0.00091
C          0.73888       -1.22664        0.00093
Cl        -1.53314       -2.71418        0.00498
Cl        -1.52136        2.66877        0.00121
O          2.79865       -0.02609       -0.00280
O          1.44835       -2.39879        0.00087
H         -2.44987       -0.02276        0.00427
H          1.26734        2.14102       -0.00216
H          3.13615        0.88329       -0.00455
H          0.80881       -3.13311        0.00244

--Link1--
%oldchk=x0_ground_low.chk
%chk=x0_ground_high.chk
%mem=80GB
%nprocshared=8
#p opt=(tight,calcfc,recalcfc=3) geom=check scf=qc b3lyp/6-311+g(2d,p) nosymm int=ultrafine

high optimization no.x0 ground

0 1
```

So what I am now looking for is to number up automatically `x0 to x1, x2 ... xn` in the Titelsection with
`low optimization no.x0` ground and high o`ptimization no.x0 ground` and also in the checkpoint files: `%chk=x0_ground_low.chk %oldchk=x0_ground_low.chk %chk=x0_ground_high.chk`
Is it possible to include variables for the x0 like in a bash-script and just change the variable at each file?
I can not write a bash script because I use slurm in a cluster as management system. So I got my slurm file which opens the .gjf-file from gaussian. So it would be nice just to modify the .gjf-file.

Thanks!

Comment: Would  you not be able to use bash/tcsh/python from within your slurm job script? The initial step of the job would just use a scripting language to format the titles and chk names and the latter portion would run that modified input file. As far as I know, Gaussian doesn't have this functionality of providing variables (besides for geometric parameters of the calculation).

Comment: I have no idea how slurm works if I am honest. I got a super short script so start slurm where I just should enter the job name of the file from gaussian

Comment: We did have an earlier question/answer about [how to write SLURM jobs](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/a/6498/7). If you know bash/python, its more or less as simple as just adding a line to call that bash/python file to write your input.

Comment: I gave my +1 long ago, but just wanted to come back and check how things are going. Did you figure this out? Are you still working on it? Let us know!

Comment: @NikeDattani I found another way with a bash script. this works much easier for me. took a while to get familiar with bash but now it is a better workflow. thanks for interest in my problem+

Comment: Are you able to write a self-answer? If you've figured this out then I don't see why it has to remain an "unanswered" question!